# std::max_element looking for -> operator

Tags: c++, stl, max

I was trying to find maximum marks of students stored in the vector. 
Here is my code. SL is vector of student object.

```
class Student{
public:
    int returnScore(){return score;}
    private:
    int score;
};
class StudentList{
public:
    vector<Student>sl;
bool compare( Student& s1,Student &s2)
    {
        return (s1.returnScore()<s2.returnScore());
    }
    void highest_score()
    {
        auto max_score = max_element(sl.begin(),sl.end(),compare);
        if(max_score == sl.end()){}
            //cout<<"Container empty.\n";
        else{}
          //  cout<<*max_score;
    }
};
int main()
{

    StudentList l;
    l.highest_score();

}
```

Compiler took me to C++ official library and gave error.

`error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (StudentList::*)(Student&, Student&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (StudentList::*)(Student&, Student&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (StudentList::*)(Student&, Student&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (StudentList::*)(Student&, Student&)>::_M_comp) (...)'|`

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Let me guess, `sl` is a vector<Student*>`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's `vector<Student>sl;`

Comment: After filling in the blanks your code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/T_MCbF, please provide a [mre]

Comment: The code you're showing us is fine, the bug is in code you're not showing us.  This is  therefore unanswerable.

Comment: @JohnZwinck  See now

Comment: @AlanBirtles see now

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt See now

Comment: Okay, so `compare` is a memberfunction. That changes *everything*. Search for the diffence between a "plain" function and a memberfunction, that should give you enough to read. As a quick fix, make it `statct` and give `&StudentList::compare` to the algorithm.

Comment: You are missing several includes, and compare should take const references

Comment: @M.M This is just to produce minimal code.

Comment: It has to be reproducible as well -- it doesn't compile as posted

Answer (score 0):

My compiler tells me that `compare` needs to be a static function, not a regular member function:

```
static bool compare( Student& s1,Student &s2)
```

Then it all compiles fine.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element Nothing static like thing here.

Comment: @NikhilSharma: You mean like where it says `static bool abs_compare(int a, int b)`?  That's a static free function which also works fine, if you want to move `compare` outside of `StudentList`.

Comment: @NikhilSharma. std::max_element requires a callable object for comparison. A method is not a callable object, because it requires an object for which it is being called. You can wrap it: max_element(sl.begin(),sl.end(),[this](Student& s1, Student& s2) {return compare(s1,s2);}); Or turn compare into a function / static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        auto max_score = max_element(sl.begin(),sl.end(),compare);
```

You can't do that because `compare` is a method and `max_element` wouldn't have the object to which this method belongs. In other words, you can't just call `compare` because you also need the object for which it is being called.

You can turn compare into a static method:

```
static bool compare( Student& s1,Student &s2)
{
    return (s1.returnScore()<s2.returnScore());
}
```

This will work.

Alternatively you can wrap the call to compare:

```
auto max_score = max_element(sl.begin(),sl.end(),[this](Student& s1,Student& s2) {return compare(s1,s2);});
```

But to me it seems like a lot of code instead of turning compare into a function/static method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, making the class member function `static` will do the job. An alternative is to define `operator<` in the Student class like

```
inline bool operator<(const Student& s2)
{
    return (this->returnScore()<s2.returnScore());
}
```

and call std::max_element (which uses the default operator<) as

```
auto max_score = max_element(sl.begin(),sl.end());
```